# Call another constructor as global inside a class

Tags: c++, constructor, arduino

I am creating a library for my DHT sensor. I have 2 files with names of `AM_2301.cpp` and `AM_2301.h`:

`AM_2301.h`:

```
#ifndef AM2301_h
#define AM2301_h

#include "Arduino.h"

struct Two_float {
    float temp;
    float humidity;
};

extern int pinn;

class AM_2301
{
  public:
    AM_2301(int pin);
    void begin();
    struct Two_float read();
  private:
    int _pin;
};

#endif
```

`AM_2301.cpp`:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "AM_2301.h"
#include "DHT.h"

//#define pinn 3
int pinn;
DHT dht(pinn, DHT21);

AM_2301::AM_2301(int pin)
{
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.print("pinn: ");
    Serial.println(pinn);
    _pin = pin;
    pinn = pin;
    //DHT dht(pinn, DHT21);
}


void AM_2301::begin(){
    dht.begin();
}

struct Two_float AM_2301::read()
{
    struct Two_float output;
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
    float t = dht.readTemperature();
    // check if returns are valid, if they are NaN (not a number) then something went wrong!
    if (isnan(t) || isnan(h))
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
        t = 0;
        h = 0;
    }
    output = {t, h};
    return output;
}
```

and `main.cpp`:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "AM_2301.h"

int pin =3 ;

AM_2301 AM(pin);

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(115200);
    AM.begin();
}

void loop() {

    struct Two_float val;
    val = AM.read();
    Serial.print("Temp: ");
    Serial.print(val.temp);
    Serial.print(" , ");
    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.println(val.humidity);
    delay(2000);
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

But the problem is I want to declare a pin number in the constructor, and that pin goes to another constructor in `AM_2301.cpp` but I don't know how to implement that. I want to make `dht` object to become global to all other functions inside my class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `DHT` object part of the `AM_2301` class and then initialize it using [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

AM_2301.h

```
#ifndef AM2301_h
#define AM2301_h

#include "Arduino.h"

struct Two_float {
    float temp;
    float humidity;
};

class AM_2301
{
  public:
    AM_2301(int pin);
    void begin();
    struct Two_float read();
  private:
    DHT dht; // add a DHT object
};

#endif
```

AM_2301.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "AM_2301.h"
#include "DHT.h"

AM_2301::AM_2301(int pin) : dht(pin, DHT21) {} // initialize the DHT object

// other code stays the same
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I access dht object in other functions in `AM_2301.cpp` like `AM_2301::read()`?

Comment: `dht(DHT(pin, DHT21))` can be simplified to `dht(pin, DHT21)`

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution according to paddy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227472/declare-class-object-globally-but-without-parameters) I had to use a pointer from my static instance. Here is the modified `AM_2301.cpp`:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "AM_2301.h"
#include "DHT.h"

static DHT *dht = NULL;  //define the pointer


AM_2301::AM_2301(int pin)
{
    pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
    Serial.print("_pin: ");
    Serial.println(_pin);
    _pin = pin;
    dht = new DHT(_pin, DHT21);  //pass the initialization
}


void AM_2301::begin(){
    dht->begin();
}

struct Two_float AM_2301::read()
{
    struct Two_float output;
    float h = dht->readHumidity();
    float t = dht->readTemperature();
    // check if returns are valid, if they are NaN (not a number) then something went wrong!
    if (isnan(t) || isnan(h))
    {
        Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT");
        t = 0;
        h = 0;
    }
    output = {t, h};
    return output;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if you decide to use multiple sensors.

Comment: @gre_gor why? Can you post the reason?

Comment: You can't have a separate DHT object for each of the AM_2301 objects.

Comment: @gre_gor ah, yes you are right but how can I have independent DHT objects for each instance?